# Solubility of cholesterol and phospholipids in acetone

Tags: biochemistry, solubility, polarity, fats

I'm having difficulty with this specific part of an assignment. I know that it is to do with polarities of the different parts of cholesterol and that it is because cholesterol is amphiphilic, but I don't know what it is about acetone that means it can dissolve amphiphilic substances but not phospholipids.

Comment: In fact, you seem to have gotten it the wrong way round. Phospholipids are a "standard" example of amphiphilic compounds. That's exactly why they form the cell membrane. And are you actually sure cholesterol is amphiphilic?

Comment: It has polar and non-polar parts, the OH group is polar and the hydrocarbon chain and rings are not, so it is surely?

Comment: It is probably a little bit amphiphilic, but I would say, perhaps not as much as a phospholipid. The -OH group is relatively small and there are four fat hydrophobic rings.